# php round to the next whole number

Tags: php

In PHP, I need to round off a number to the next whole number. For example, in my program, I am using the round as below.

```
$val = round(count($names)/15);
```

If **count($names)** is 1.2, I need it to be rounded off to 2 instead of 1. I tried to do the below approach.

```
  $val = round(count($names)/15) + 1;
```

However, in the above approach, if I have **count($names)** as 1.6, It is getting rounded off to 3 as I increment it by 1.

Is there a way where no matter what the decimal value is, it needs to be rounded off to the next whole number?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about using `ceil()`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.ceil.php

Then your code becomes:

```
$val = ceil(count($names)/15);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
$val = round(count($names)/15, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN) + 1;
```